# Java won't recognize classpath set by command line

Tags: java, eclipse

Here is my code:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("java.class.path="+System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
        ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();

        URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader)cl).getURLs();

        for(URL url: urls){
            System.out.println(url.getFile());
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this in Eclipse with the LWJGL and Slick2d libraries, I get, as expected:

```
java.class.path=/home/the-genius/workspace/classpath/bin:/home/the-geniu/workspace      
/libs/slick/lib/slick.jar:/home/the-genius/workspace/libs/lwjgl/lwjgl-2.9.2/jar  
/lwjgl.jar:/home/the-genius/workspace/libs/lwjgl/lwjgl-2.9.2/jar/lwjgl_util.jar:
/home/the-genius/workspace/libs/lwjgl/lwjgl-2.9.2/jar/jinput.jar
/home/the-genius/workspace/classpath/bin/
/home/the-genius/workspace/libs/slick/lib/slick.jar
/home/the-genius/workspace/libs/lwjgl/lwjgl-2.9.2/jar/lwjgl.jar
/home/the-genius/workspace/libs/lwjgl/lwjgl-2.9.2/jar/lwjgl_util.jar
/home/the-genius/workspace/libs/lwjgl/lwjgl-2.9.2/jar/jinput.jar
```

However, when I export it as a runnable jar and execute via

```
java -cp /home/the-genius/workspace/classpath/bin:/home/the-geniu/workspace      
/libs/slick/lib/slick.jar:/home/the-genius/workspace/libs/lwjgl/lwjgl-2.9.2/jar  
/lwjgl.jar:/home/the-genius/workspace/libs/lwjgl/lwjgl-2.9.2/jar/lwjgl_util.jar: -jar app.jar
```

I get

```
java.class.path=classpath.jar
/home/the-genius/classpath.jar
```

Is there any reason for this to be happening? How do I fix it?

I'm running on Ubuntu, if that makes a difference. I've also tried it using both OpenJDK-7 and Sun Java-7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `-cp` and `-jar` option at the same, the former is ignored. To fix it, you can either run it without `-jar`(add your jar file to the classpath and call the main class: `java -cp app.jar App`) or add the classpath to the jar manifest file.